# How to find an author biography as mentioned in papers?

Tags: publications, cv

Some papers include the authors' biographies. Given a researcher, how to quickly find his biography mentioned one of their papers? Is tedious to have to go through their papers one by one to try to find it.

Here is the kind of authors' biographies I'm referring to ([fictive example](http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive/phd081606s.gif), turned out to pop up first on Google):

[image]

Comment: Find a journal that does these, search the publications list to see if they have a paper there?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Kimball I need to get the bio of a several researchers, whose websites don't contain it.

Comment: Some people just don't share such information. Best bet is trying to contact them directly, asking for the relevant data and permission to put it to whatever use you are contemplating.

Comment: In addition to what @vonbrand says, copying a biography and using it in something else may be a copyright violation.

Comment: @Kimball Sure, I'll just make a personal use.

Comment: @vonbrand I'm just interested in author biographies present in a paper (i.e., the information is already shared).

Comment: If you want biographical information about an author, why not visit their web page?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Not listed there.

Comment: Did you try ResearchGate?